# Inserting month columns before quarters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project where I have sales data broken down into quarters. What I need to do is in front of each column insert the three months that belong in that quarter. I started with a select case statement, but then realized that probably isn't the best way to do it. What I want to do is have it be a variable range (there can be anything from 1-10 years pasted in) so I set it up to search InStr for "Q1", "Q2" and then insert the rows and proper month titles. I haven't inserted month titles yet, because I want to get the rows inserted first, but if you have a suggestion on how to do that without specifying cell values that'd also be awesome! it's also worth mentioning this data insertion starts on column U and will every time. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

```
Sub InsertMonths()
If cell.value = InStr(1, cell, "Q1", 1) Then
    Dim y As String
    y = InStr(1, cell, "Q1", 1)
    If y = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim x As Long
    For x = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 18).value = y Then
    Columns(x + 3).Resize(1).Insert
    End If
    Next x
Else cell.value = InStr(1, cell, "Q2", 1) Then
    Dim y As String
    y = InStr(1, cell, "Q2", 1)
    If y = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim x As Long
    For x = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 18).value = y Then
    Columns(x + 3).Resize(1).Insert
    End If
    Next x
Else InStr(1, cell, "Q3", 1) then
    Dim y As String
    y = InStr(1, cell, "Q3", 1)
    If y = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim x As Long
    For x = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 18).value = y Then
    Columns(x + 3).Resize(1).Insert
    End If
    Next x
Else InStr(1, cell, "Q4", 1) then
    Dim y As String
    y = InStr(1, cell, "Q4", 1)
    If y = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim x As Long
    For x = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(x, 18).value = y Then
    Columns(x + 3).Resize(1).Insert
    End If
    Next x
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need the months in separate columns, or in one column but comma separated?

Comment: Seperate columns, we're trying to associate quantity with it along the same time which is organized by month.

Comment: okay, and are you using .NET or vba?  You have both tags.

Comment: VBA, I'll take the vb.net down. Just used to working with it so I tagged it without thinking. My bad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without coming into too much detail in the exact situation, here you have a couple of loops doing the same than your set of conditions. It is prepared to deal with as many cells as required (letters and ints).

```
Sub InsertMonths()

    Dim startInt, endInt, totLetters, lettersCount, curInt As Integer
    Dim allLetters(10), curLetter, curCell As String

    totLetters = 1
    allLetters(1) = "Q"


    startInt = 1
    endInt = 4

    lettersCount = 0
    Do
        lettersCount = lettersCount + 1
        curLetter = allLetters(lettersCount)

        curInt = startInt - 1
        Do
            curInt = curInt + 1

            curCell = curLetter & CStr(curInt)
            If cell.Value = InStr(1, cell, curCell, 1) Then
                Dim y As String
                y = InStr(1, cell, curCell, 1)
                If y = "" Then Exit Sub
                Dim x As Long
                For x = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(x, 18).Value = y Then
                Columns(x + 3).Resize(1).Insert
                End If
                Next x
            End If
        Loop While (curInt < endInt)
    Loop While (curLetter < totLetters)

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried to simplify it a bit, this has definitely set me in the right direction though. I only need to search the top row, thats where the Qx will be. I can't quite figure it out, but it would seem that I'd make a variable and then replace the cell.value with the row variable

    If cell.value = InStr(1, cell, curCell, 1) Then
                Dim x2 As Long
                For x2 = Cells(Columns.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(1, x).value = curCell Then
                Columns(x - 3).Resize(1).Insert
                End If
                Next x2

Comment: I am not sure what is exactly what you are looking for (what the first row should contain) but I am under the impression that you are over-complicating things. Knowing the values of a cell is very easy: Range("A1").Value or Cells(1, 1).Value You can create a simple loop going through the column Q checking values and getting the row number of the cell having the target value. Also you might rely on .Find function but, in your situation, I would better learn to use loops and read cells properly before moving forward to more complex functionalities.

Comment: Yeah, you know what they say. Practice makes perfect. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I wanna apologize, I was lazy in posting this question. What I did was replace all the FY's with just the quarter, and that made it much easier. Thanks again, and sorry if I bothered you.

Comment: No problem. Although the less clear is the problem, the more difficult is giving a solution. You can go ahead then and select the answer which you have found more helpful as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where you are setting the value in the cell to hold the month, put the following formula instead of the value

```
Cells(x, y).value = "=(MID($D2,2,1) - 1) * 3 + 1"
```

Second column would be

```
Cells(x, y).value = "=(MID($D2,2,1) - 1) * 3 + 2"
```

And third would be

```
Cells(x, y).value = "=(MID($D2,2,1) - 1) * 3 + 3"
```

In all of the cases above, the $D2 should reference the cell you found to contain the "Q#".  The formulas are basically taking the numerical part of the quarter and calculating the 1st, 2nd and 3rd months of the quarter.

Also note that this gives you the month number.  If you want the name, you should be able to figure that out.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That'll definitely do the trick for the months...now I just have to figure out how to loop it properly.